# get the size of dataset after applying a filter from tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, filter, size, take

I wonder how I can get the size or the len of the dataset after applying a filter. Using tf.data.experimental.cardinality give -2, and this is not what I am looking for!! I want to know how many filtered samples exist in my dataset in order to be able to split it to training and validation datasets using take() and skip().

Example:

```py
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x: x < 4)
    size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset).numpy()
    #size here is equal to -2 but I want to get the real size which is 3
```

My dataset contains images and their labels, this is just an illustrative example

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have updated the post, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation reveals that a cardinality of -2 shows that Tensorflow is unable to determine the cardinality of the data set. You can find this in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental#INFINITE_CARDINALITY). For your example, you can do

```
dataset = dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
dataset = list(dataset)
print(len(dataset))
```

Comment: Yes I saw this in the documentation. The problem is that I have a huge dataset and (len(list(dataset))) will not work

Comment: If this is the case, you can use the reduce method to create a sort of counter that increments with each element in your data set. This could be dataset.reduce(0, lambda x,_: x+1).numpy()

Comment: Thank you but this method seems also to be very slow ...

Comment: @Lukas if the filtering depends on the processed data any method to count the dataset after filtering will be slow because you still need to consume each sample to check if it has to be filtered or not. You can probably speed up thinks if you do some minimal (hopefully faster) computation enough for the filtering, count and then finish processing.

Comment: I ended up using @Richard X second proposition. It is working fine on my new dataset